# write json string in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am using json developing android sdk.
I found writing json string is annoying, take a look:

```
post_my_server("{\"cmd\":\"new_comment\"}");
```

I need to manually escape quotes, is there any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use single quotes "{'cmd':'new_comment'}".

Alternatively, there is free code at http://json.org/java/ for implementing JSON at an object level. It's free as in very permissive, I am no lawyer, but it would seem that the only stipulation is that the software you include it in is good, and not evil.

Answer (score 2):

```
To create json string use jackson core jars. The code snippet to generate a sample json string ,

JsonFactory jFactory = new JsonFactory();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
/*** write to string ***/
JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jFactory.createJsonGenerator(writer);
jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
jsonGenerator.writeStringField("company", [Value]);
jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("salary", [value]); 
jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
jsonGenerator.close();
String jsonString = writer.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the jackson json parsers and serializers , they are completely self contained, and allow for reading, writing of any java object to and from json.

Assume you have a file called "user.json" which contains a big json in it....

`private static void convert(){
    Map<String,Object> userData = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), Map.class); 
}`

Comment: The Jackson JSON libraries are great.